# RecordSet.Update Error after Upgrading from Oracle 11g to 19c

Tags: database, oracle, recordset, migrate

I am getting the following error:
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error ‘80004005’
[Oracle][ODBC]SQL data type out of range <-27>

The line that this error pops up on is always "RecordSet.update" in several of my asp files. An example is below:

```
'***************************
' Insert System into table
'**************************
Sub insert_UI
'On Error Resume Next
    Set recordSet= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    recordSet.open "Select * from UI_CODES", connectionToDatabase,1,2
    recordSet.Addnew
    contact_field = array ("UI_code", "Description")
    For each x in contact_field
        recordset(x) = request(x)
    Next 
    RecordSet.update
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Call Error_handling
    Else 
        print_default
    End If
    recordSet.close
    set recordSet= nothing
End Sub
```

This code is working fine on Oracle 11g. However, after migrating over to Oracle 19c, this error pops up. Was there some change between the versions that could be causing this? If so, is there a new work around for it?
The OS is Windows Server 2019.

Thanks if you can help or provide suggestions.

After some research, I read it may an issue from 32 bit to 64bit. I changed it to be compatible in the IIS settings, but still see the same issue.